# Using SED to comment out SSL in NGINX.CONF file

Tags: bash, sed

In the pursuit of automation, I am trying to comment out and comment in certain pieces of code. Please note,  this is part of a script so I am trying to isolate specific lines that have **#ssl_system**

Before

```
#return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri; #ssl_system

#} #ssl_system

#server { #ssl_system

    # SSL configuration 
    #listen 443 ssl; #ssl_system
    #listen [::]:443 ssl; #ssl_system
    expires $expires;
    #include snippets/ssl-newdomain.com.conf; #ssl_system
    #include snippets/ssl-params.conf; #ssl_system
```

After

```
return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri; #ssl_system

} #ssl_system

server { #ssl_system

    # SSL configuration 
    listen 443 ssl; #ssl_system
    listen [::]:443 ssl; #ssl_system
    expires $expires;
    include snippets/ssl-newdomain.com.conf; #ssl_system
    include snippets/ssl-params.conf; #ssl_system
```

Effectively it is a way of enabling and disabling SSL.

I am trying to use SED:

This works:

```
sudo sed -i -e "s|#server_name newdomain.com www.newdomain.com; #ssl_system|server_name newdomain.com www.newdomain.com; #ssl_system|g" "/var/www/srv/templates/nginx.tpl"
```

This does not:

```
sudo sed -i "s|#return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri; #ssl_system|return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri; #ssl_system|g" "/var/www/srv/templates/nginx.tpl"
```

I would like to have a set of commands that enable the SSL, and another set of commands that disable it.

I am not quite sure what I'm doing wrong however, any insight would be great.

**UPDATE**

This worked

```
sudo sed -i "s|#return 301 https://[$]server_name[$]request_uri; #ssl_system|return 301 https://[$]server_name[$]request_uri; #ssl_system|g" "/var/www/srv/templates/nginx.tpl"
```

Comment: `$` matches end of line. If you want to match a literal dollar sign, that's `\$` or `[$]`.  Your sample data doesn't contain matches for either of these regexes so hard to say exactly if that's the complete fix.

Comment: @tripleee `sudo sed -i "s|#return 301 https://[$]server_name[$]request_uri; #ssl_system|return 301 https://[$]server_name[$]request_uri; #ssl_system|g" "/var/www/srv/templates/nginx.tpl"` worked.

Answer (score 0):

***Enable*** action:

```
sed -Ei 's/^([[:space:]]*)#(return|\}|server|listen|include)/\1\2/' file.conf
```

---

***Disable*** action:

```
sed -Ei 's/^([[:space:]]*)(return|\}|server|listen|include)/\1#\2/' file.conf
```

Comment: Hello. I have just tried that and it works but I failed to mention that I have a complete script. My apologies. I will update my main question.